# Android BroadcastReceiver nullpointerexception on registering

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-launcher, android-download-manager

I'm Trying to receive a download completed action but it says the broadcast receiver is null on registering.
But I checked it and it clearly isn't.

[image: The LogCat Error]

```
public class UpdateHandler extends Activity{

    private DownloadManager manager;

    /**
     * Class Constructor will only be used for non-static Referencing in a static condition.
     */
    public UpdateHandler(DownloadManager dm){
        this.manager = dm;  
    }


    public void updateApp(final String appname) {

        String apkurl = apk_url + appname;
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                Uri.parse(apkurl));
        request.setDescription("Even geduld aub...");
        request.setTitle("Bimii-app wordt gedownload");
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, appname);

        File folder1 = android.os.Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS
                        + "/" + appname);
        if (folder1.exists()) {
            Log.d("!--->", Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + appname
                    + " pre-existant, delete!");
            folder1.delete();
        } else {
            Log.d("!--->", Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + appname
                    + " is new.");
        }

        registerBroadcastReceiver(request, appname);
    }


    /**
     * Installing a specific Application by name.
     * @param appname
     */
    private void installUpdates(String appname) {
        Log.d("installing ", appname);
        File filepath = android.os.Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS
                        + "/" + appname);

        Intent install_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        install_intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(filepath),
                "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        install_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);     
        startActivity(install_intent);
    }


    private void registerBroadcastReceiver(DownloadManager.Request request, final String appname){
        // get download service and enqueue file
        manager.enqueue(request);

        BroadcastReceiver downloadDone = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("!--->", "File Download Completed + appname");
                installUpdates(appname);
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(downloadDone, new IntentFilter(
                DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }
}
```

And this is how I initialize my UpdateHandler as requested.
This happens in my home activity.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Initialization
    init();

    loadApps();
    update_handler = new UpdateHandler((DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE));
    setupButtons();
    loadListView();
}
```

The android version I'm running is 4.2.2 in case that matters.

Comment: have you declared it in your manifest file?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Perhaps with an example?

Comment: @RoseBlax  please post your complete code, so we can help you quickly to solve your problem.

Comment: for an example please refer [this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#broadcastreceiver_platformfilter)

Comment: @DurgeshPatel there you go sir.

Comment: @RoseBlax have you initialized instance of manager?

Comment: @DurgeshPatel Yes I have, Look I've added that bit of code aswell, as requested.

Comment: @RoseBlax can you post some code what init() and loadApps() does because we need to know is there anything related to this crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an activity/Application context for registering the broadcast receiver.

As I can see from screenshot, you are registering receiver from utils.UpdateHandler file so you need to pass application context to this method.

So code will be

```
/**
     * Class Constructor will only be used for non-static Referencing in a static condition.
     */
    public UpdateHandler(Context context, DownloadManager dm){
        this.mContext = context;
        this.manager = dm;  
    }
```

and then call context.registerReceiver()

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: UpdateHandler does not need to extend an Activity and you should make a variable Context context which refers to HomeActivity in your code.

Comment: and which method do you suggested using for getting the proper context from the main activity?

Comment: I am using getBaseContext() from the main activity and parsing that. This solved it. Thanks allot.

Answer (score 1):

> In your UpdateHandler class the `context` is not initialized yet.
>   Because you are just extending the `Activity` class. Without calling
>   the `Activity's` lifecycle method (eg:`onCreate`) the context will not
>   be available to you. It will be null.

So I suggest you pass the context from your `HomeActivity` to the `UpdateHandler` class through the constructor and use that context to register the receiver.

change your UpdateHandler like this

```
public class UpdateHandler{
    private DownloadManager manager;
    private Context mContext
    public UpdateHandler(Context mContext,DownloadManager dm){
        this.manager = dm;  
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }
```

and to register your receiver use this

```
context.registerReceiver(downloadDone, new IntentFilter(
                DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

Also you dont want to extend UpdateHandler class with Activity

Comment: This is an more elaborate version of @maveroids solution, this ended up working for me. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Ya. you should accept @maveroids answer. I just added some explanation to it